# Почему перескакивают элементы в грид контейнере?

Tags: html, css, css3, css-grid

Почему элементы не сужаются? А перескакивают сразу не дойдя до свей минимальной ширины?
https://jsfiddle.net/baar6uoj/

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 200px));
  grid-gap: 20px;
}

.grid div {
  background-color: #28314E;
  border: 1px solid #212941;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 15px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: roboto;
}

.grid div:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #475477;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div>item-1</div>
  <div>item-2</div>
  <div>item-3</div>
  <div>item-4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дело в том, что это и есть нормальная работа функции `minmax`, которую вы наблюдаете. Я тоже был удивлён сперва, но это просто так она создана, такова задумка создателей.

### Как работает функция `minmax`?

Cперва пробуется примениться "максимальный" размер. И только если "минимум" в пикселях будет больше "максимума", то применяется "минимальный". Но всегда по умолчанию применяется "максимум". Поэтому эта функция хороша в комбинации гибких единиц и фиксированных (в данном случае — переменного количества колонок). К примеру `minmax(100px, 1fr)`.

### Как срабатывает `mimmax` в данном примере?

Всё-таки колонки сужаются. Только в случае если доступная ширина контейнера меньше `200px`.

А до достижения этого условия, элементы без проблем переносятся на новые строки совершенно не уменьшаясь. Поскольку для применения "максимума" нет никаких проблем, то колонки не сужаются, а переносятся. Всё дело в том, что по умолчанию применяется максимум, а минимум в данном случае не будет применяться, так как для его достижения нужно, чтобы он был больше в пискелях, чем максимум, а этого не происходит, так как `100px` всегда будут меньше `200px`.

Comment: Ага, понял. Типа Если есть возможность сделать ширину "максимальной", но браузер это сделает всеми способами в моём случае путём переноса строки

Comment: И только если "минимум" в пикселях будет больше "максимума", то применяется "минимальный" Это как???

Comment: @АртёмPeGaS Это наглядно проявляется, к примеру, в гибких единицах и фиксированных единицах. К примеру, для значения `minmax(200px, 1fr)` строка будет занимать всё оставшееся место, но не меньше `200px`.

Comment: @АртёмPeGaS Так понятно?

Comment: Я по этому оперирую "Если есть возможность сделать ширину "максимальной", но браузер это сделает"